# How to select a row that contains a column with a specific text?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Picture the following table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried it this way using CSS selectors.

```
tr td [innerHTML="Valor 1"]{
  background: red;
}
```

I would like to color the line that has the column with "Valor 1". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :nth-child(1) property, or javascript for this. But if you want to use only css-way you should add to you td data-attribute, and after this you can use something like this: `td[data-attr="Valor 1"] { ... }` Here is my css solutions example https://jsfiddle.net/L1gsq73t/

Comment: No way without the use of `data-attribute`?

Comment: Sorry, I don`t know another way to do it(

Answer (score 0):

A few lines of javascript will ensure that each of your table rows has a class corresponding to the text content of the data cell within that table row.

From there, you can simply declare styles for one, several or all of the classes.

**Working Example:**

```js
var dataCells = [... document.getElementsByTagName('td')];

dataCells.forEach(function(dataCell){
    var rowClass;
    rowClass = dataCell.textContent;
    rowClass = rowClass.replace(/\s/g, '');
    rowClass = rowClass.toLowerCase();
    dataCell.parentNode.classList.add(rowClass);
});
```

```css
.valor1 {
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Valor 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use JS for this. Assign all table cells to an array then check each one till you find the one you want and set the Background value

```
function searchCells(){
    var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++){
        if(cells[i].InnerHTML == "Valor 1"){
            cells[i].Background = "red";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

A tested functional solution with jQuery:

```
$( "table tr td:contains('Valor 1')" ).css( "background", "red" );
```

Comment: It also does not mention that I cannot.